# Object order for NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nskeyedarchiver

As per my understanding full object graph is stored using:

NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject

and it gets retrieved in the same order it was saved, is this correct?

I am getting a NSDictionary and want to save the objects in the same order in which it was received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your NSDictionary contains an array (as you stated in a comment on a different answer), that array will be preserved. NSKeyedArchiver simply saves the object, it doesn't have anything to do with the order. So to answer your question, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The order of elements in NSDictionary is undefined, so even if you read them in the same order as they were written and then iterate through them, the order may not be the same as initially.

Comment: My NSDictionary contains a NSArray wherein I want to retain the order. So, will NSKeyedArchiver return me the same order?